# What is this part with crossbars in my bathtub drain called?

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

This is in my bathtub and I need a new rubber gasket for it.  The gasket sits between the bottom of the tub and the top of this PVC attachment.  The X has a bolt that threads into it through the drain strainer/stopper to essentially sandwich the pipe to the bottom of the tub.

I have tried Googling in various ways but I can't even find this type of PVC attachment anywhere. I'd just like to know the name of it so I can ensure I buy the correct gasket to seal it.

Thanks!

[image: The thing in question]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Drain shoe**, though that's an abnormal one. It's a part specific to bathtubs.

Most have threads on the inside diameter and the inside-the-tub part has mating threads and may have the "stopper cross" as well. But since all you need is the gasket, no problem.

**Bath Shoe Gasket** seems to be the search term you'll want.

There appears to be a great deal of debate about installing them with no sealant, plumber's putty, or silicone rubber caulking. The maker of *my* tub specified caulking. So I did, and I let it cure undisturbed for several days, and it's held. Apprently the oils in plumber's putty can negatively affect some plastic tubs.

Comment: Also, putty doesn't do well against surfaces that need to rotate to compress.  If the compression is done without rotation of the sealing surfaces (like a garbage disposal flange), no problem.

Comment: Ok that's information I didn't know with the putty, so appreciate that. I did just find the specific brand just after you answered so I'll check their information sheet on whether to putty/silicone or not and order the shoe gasket through them. Thanks to you both!  https://parts.maax.com/zMAAX/public/PartsOnline?country=us&lang=en#